# beautifulsoup to csv: putting paragraph of text into one line

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I have a bunch of web text that I'd like to scrape and export to a csv file. The problem is that the text is split over multiple lines on the website and that's how beautifulsoup reads it. When I export to csv, all the text goes into one cell but the cell has multiple lines of text. When I try to read the csv into another program, it interprets the multiple lines in a way that yields a nonsensical dataset. The question is, how do I put all the text into a single line after I pull it with beautifulsoup but before I export to csv?

Here's a simple working example demonstrating the problem of multiple lines (in fact, the first few lines in the resulting csv are blank, so at first glance it may look empty):

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    r = requests.get("https://www.econometricsociety.org/publications/econometrica/2017/03/01/search-yield")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    with open('Temp.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
        abstract=soup.find("article").text
        writer.writerow([abstract])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

UPDATE: there have been some good suggestions, but it's still not working. The following code still produces a csv file with line breaks in a cell:

```
import csv    
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('Temp.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    r = requests.get("https://www.econometricsociety.org/publications/econometrica/2017/03/01/search-yield")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml') 
    find_article = soup.find('article')
    find_2para = find_article.p.find_next_sibling("p")
    find_largetxt = find_article.p.find_next_sibling("p").nextSibling
    writer.writerow([find_2para,find_largetxt])
```

Here's another attempt based on a different suggestion. This one also ends up producing a line break in the csv file:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    r = requests.get("https://www.econometricsociety.org/publications/econometrica/2017/03/01/search-yield")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    with open('Temp.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
        abstract=soup.find("article").get_text(separator=" ", strip=True)
        writer.writerow([abstract])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What are some of the typical pieces of text that you want to scrape from the page?

Comment: Is it possible that you want only the following items?: (1) Econometrica: Mar 2017, Volume 85, Issue 2 (2) Search for Yield (3) David Martinez‐Miera, Rafael Repullo (4) We present a model of the relationship between real interest rates, credit spreads, and the structure and risk of the banking system. Banks intermediate between entrepreneurs and investors, and can monitor entrepreneurs' projects. We characterize the equilibrium for a fixed aggregate supply of savings, ...

Comment: Actually, I just want (4). If there's an easy way to get that, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that ended up working for me is pretty simple:

```
abstract=soup.find("article").text.replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
```

That gets rid of all line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `abstract = ...` line into:

```
abstract = soup.find("article").get_text(separator=" ", strip=True)
```

It'll separate each line using the separator parameter (in this case It'll separate the strings with an empty space.

Comment: That definitely looks better but for some reason there's still a line break between "p." and "351-378" in "p. 351-378", which again causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.get("https://www.econometricsociety.org/publications/econometrica/2017/03/01/search-yield")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml') # I prefer using xml parser
find_article = soup.find('article')
# Next line how to find The title in this case: Econometrica: Mar 2017, Volume 85, Issue 2
find_title = find_article.h3
# find search yeild 
find_yeild = find_article.h1
#first_paragraph example : DOI: 10.3982/ECTA14057       p. 351-378
find_1para =  find_article.p
#second p example : David Martinez‐Miera, Rafael Repullo  
find_2para = find_article.p.find_next_sibling("p")
#find the large text area using e.g. 'We present a model of the relationship bet...'
find_largetxt = find_article.p.find_next_sibling("p").nextSibling
```

I used a variety of methods of getting to the text area you wish just for the purpose of education(you can use .text on each of these to get the text without tags or you can use Zroq's method.
But you can write each one of these into the file by doing for example

```
writer.writerow(find_title.text)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! (although FYI I had to replace the periods in "find.article" with underscores).

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'll get to it now :), don't forget to mark the question as answered if everything is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working well. When I write to csv, the entry is still getting split over multiple lines, causing problems. Here's what' I'm writing for the csv writer part. (also, it won't let me add ".text", complaining that 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text')

with open('Temp.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",") 
    writer.writerow([find_2para,find_largetxt])

Comment: I'll take a look at it later if I don't forget. Maybe our friend's code does the job, give it a shoot.

Comment: Do you mean Zroq? I tried adding ".nextSibling.get_text(separator=" ", strip=True)" at the end of find_largetxt and find_2para, but got the same 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text' error...

Comment: Could you edit your question and add that information ( and a screenshot or traceback )  that'll be a lot more helpful

Comment: Added two code attempts that still produce line breaks, one based on your suggestion, one based on Zroq's.